# Transform number to specific string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I can't seem to get my head around javascript regex, so I need your help!

I need to transform the following:

1234567891230

Into:

urn:epc:id:sgln:12345678.9123.0

I already did it with a normal javascript algorithm (see underneath), but we need to be able to configure this transformation. I just need it for the default configuration value!

Using slice it would be:

```
var result = "urn:epc:id:sgln:" + myString.slice(0, 8) + "." + 
myString.slice(8, 12) + "." + myString.slice(12);
```

If you can include an explanation in your answer I would be grateful :)

Comment: What have you tried? And what does "I already did it with a normal javascript algorithm, but we need to be able to configure this transformation." mean?

Comment: What's the logic? Like why a dot after `8` and `3`? Why the extra `0`?

Comment: What is wrong with what you have done so far?

Comment: rmlan: I included the "javascript" algorithm in the question. I am not very familiar with regex, so I have basically tried to stitch pieces together from similar problems.

Comment: rmlan: We want to store the regex in a database, so that we can transform the number in various ways and not have it hard coded. Our current problem is that a customers test environment doesn't use the same "urn:epc:id:sgln:" prefix.

Comment: You'll probably find that "normal javascript algorithm" would be more configurable.

Comment: Is the prefix the only thing that changes? Also, use the @ symbol to make sure that your comment makes it to my inbox.

Comment: @rmlan the dots could theoretically also change position, but always 2 dots. Also the zero at the end could be another integer, but most likely won't happen.

Comment: @rmlan Actually forget what I said about the zero at the end. It is part of the input number. I edited the question to match.

Comment: Maybe it makes more sense to just be able to configure the prefix and dot positions specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex to capture 3 groups for `12345678`, `9123` and `0` and use a word boundary `\b` at the begin and at the end.

Then using [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) you could get all elements but leave out the first element from the array returned by [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) because that contains the full match that we don't need.

After that you could [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the elements from the array using the dot as the separator.

[`\b(\d{8})(\d{4})(\d)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/yn30pm/1)

```js
let str = "1234567891230";
let prefix = "urn:epc:id:sgln:";
console.log(prefix + str.match(/\b(\d{8})(\d{4})(\d)\b/).slice(1).join("."));
```

Comment: Thanks for this.

I think we will go ahead and use your solution. It means we will have two configuration values; one for the prefix (string) and one for inserting dots at the right places (regex).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use regex for this try the following:

```js
var regex = /(\d{8})(\d{4})/;
var splittedNumber = regex.exec("123456789123");
var result = "urn:epc:id:sgln:"+splittedNumber[1]+"."+splittedNumber[2]+".0";
console.log(result);
```

But I would recommend the string split you did already.